# Does "blanket charge" have two distinct meanings?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I couldn't find definitions for "**blanket charge**". What I've gathered from my Google searches is that the term seems to have two distinct meanings:

> 1. A lump sum that is charged (Google find: "...his services were not included in the $750 blanket charge.")
> 2. An overly generalized accusation (Google find: "The blanket charge is often made by TNOJ purists and others that Dixieland jazz was
>      merely the white musicians' watering down of the black players'
>      TNOJ.")

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Blanket charge* has these two different meanings because *charge* has two different meanings<sup>†</sup>: the payment required for goods or services and an accusation.

*Blanket* is a metaphorical use designating something which "covers" everything involved, as a blanket covers a bed. *Blanket* may be applied in this sense to other entities than charges: blanket statement, blanket insurance, blanket ban, blanket amnesty, and the like.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Two different meanings which are relevant here—*charge* has other meanings as well.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I've only heard the term "blanket charge" used to mean a lump-sum fee.

> "I went on a weekend cruise and all of the food, drinks and airfare, were included in the blanket charge of $1000."

I can tell from the *context* of your other example, `The blanket charge is often made by TNOJ purists...` that it is referring to an alternate meaning of the word **charge**.

**Charge** has many [meanings](https://www.google.ca/search?q=charge%20definition), see below.

- Your **example #1 refers to definition #1** below.
- Your **example #2 refers to definition #2** below.

To simplify your example:

> "The blanket charge is often made by TNOJ purists and others that Dixieland jazz was merely the white musicians' watering down of the black players' TNOJ."

- **blanket charge** = accusation
- **TNOJ** = a New Orleans Jazz Music
- **Purists** = a group who dioesn't like change
- **watering down** = oversimplifying

---

So,

### "The black musicians accuse the white musicians of oversimplifying jazz music."

---

## CHARGE (as a NOUN):

1. - a price asked for goods or services. ("an admission charge") - *synonyms*:  fee, payment, price, tariff, amount, sum, fare, levy
2. - an **accusation**, typically one formally made against a prisoner brought to trial.  ("he appeared in court on a **charge** of attempted murder") - *synonyms*: accusation, allegation, indictment, arraignment
     ("he pleaded guilty to the charge")
3. - the responsibility of taking care or control of someone or something. ("the people in her charge are pupils and not experimental subjects") - *synonyms*:   care, protection, safekeeping, control; More
     custody, guardianship, wardship; ("the child was in her charge")
   - a person or thing entrusted to the care of someone. ("the babysitter watched over her charges") - *synonyms*: ward, protégé, dependent
   - a responsibility or onerous duty assigned to someone. - *synonyms*:   duty, responsibility, task, job, assignment, mission, function; ("his charge was to save the business")
   - an official instruction, especially one given by a judge to a jury regarding points of law. ("the judge gave a careful charge to the jury") - *synonyms*: instruction, direction, directive, order, command, dictate
4. - the property of matter that is responsible for *electrical* phenomena, existing in a positive or negative form.
   - the quantity of matter responsible for electrical phenomena carried by a body.
   - energy stored chemically for conversion into electricity.
   - an act or process of storing electrical energy in a battery.
   - informal: a thrill. ("I get a real charge out of working hard") - *synonyms:* thrill, tingle, glow, excitement, stimulation, enjoyment, pleasure;
5. - a quantity of explosive to be detonated, typically in order to fire a gun or similar weapon.
6. - a headlong rush forward, typically one made by attacking soldiers in battle. ("a cavalry charge") - *synonyms*: attack, assault, offensive, onslaught ("an infantry charge")

There are also different meanings as a VERB.